# how to find all directories in /home that are not owned by root and change their permissions to ensure they have 711 permission?

Tags: linux

I try to find all directories in /home that are not owned by root and change their permissions to ensure they have 711 permission in the same command.

```
find \home type -d -not -user root -ls | chmod 711 {} \
```

But the command I used doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The first instruction has wrong syntax. You could try:

```
find /home -type d -not -user root -ls
```

Also, you shouldn't use "ls" if you care about performance. Instead I suggest using the -exec switch.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
find /home -type d -not -user root -exec chmod 711 {} +
```

The `-exec` action allows you to run a separate executable (in this case `chmod`) and supply the found names to it.  The `+` at the end allows find to run `chmod` with multiple names at once.

The above includes fixes for a few typos: `\home` should be `/home`, `type -d` should be `-type d`.